# Region doesn't show the blocks content

Tags: 7, theming

I can't see a content of custom block (making by clicking on "Add new block").

I try to add block in region, but region doesn't show the block content. I use different kinds of block("Search form", "Powered by Drupal", etc.) and it doesn't help.

What should i do?

Comment: Please provide more detail on what you've tried and what you've entered.

Comment: I add more detail

Comment: We need more specific information. What is the content in your block? Is the region one you created? Are any blocks showing in any regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new block then yo have to specify whether the block should be visible in all pages or specific pages in the **Show block on specific pages** save it.
also while assigning the block to any particular region you need to save the block by clicking on save blocks button at the bottom of the blocks page.